# Visual Studio 2017 is not executing any code nor generating any meaningful errors

Tags: c#, visual-studio, console-application

I am having trouble with Visual Studio, so I created as simple a program as I could. I created a Console Application that should display a single line to the console, then wait for the user to press a key. Instead, it gives me an error message.

I looked up the error message, and it is discussing an invalid handle. I am not sure what handle could possibly be invalid. The code is not in any way complex (and would have worked without issue any other day I've used Visual Studio). I have no clue what could have possibly caused this issue. I have not used Visual Studio in about two and a half weeks, but I still cannot fathom what could have happened to it in that time.

Here is a screen shot of the error message:
[image: Visual Studio Error]

I've been to Microsoft Help and Support web sites (although I did not find any web site specifically named Help and Support, but I did find MSDN and the various forums). I looked up that HRESULT. In every article I read, it is discussing some Web application error. I have yet to come across a single article that mentions this occurring in a Console application, which is why I am so stymied. My next step is to try to repair my installation of the .NET Framework to see if that does anything (I found some oblique references saying that may help). If anyone else has any ideas, I am very interested!

Additionally, I tried this same code in Visual Studio 2013. It runs fine with that IDE. It only fails with Visual Studio 2017 (which I have had nothing but problems with since installing it, and uninstalling and reinstalling it). But, my copy of VS 2013 is the Community edition, and my job just purchased the Professional license for 2017 for me, so I would prefer to use that if I can ever get it to work. It is quite frustrating at this point. If I cannot find any other answer, my next resort is uninstalling it and reinstalling it again. This will make the fifth or sixth time that I have needed to do that, so I am hoping for another solution.

Edit:
Doing more research, I discovered it is only an issue when debugging code. If I run code through Visual Studio using the 'Start Without Debugging' option, it runs without issue. And since I am able to use VS 2013 on the same machine in debug mode without issue, that seems to rule out a Windows issue. The issue is probably confined to VS 2017.

I have plans to uninstall and reinstall VS 2017, but that is a lengthy process. So, before I do that, I am still looking for any other possible solutions.

UPDATE:

I found the crash report in Event Viewer. Here is the log:

> Fault bucket 2243818120991372909, type 1
> Event Name: APPCRASH
> Response: Not available
> Cab Id: 0
>
> Problem signature:
> P1: HelloWorldTest3.exe
> P2: 1.0.0.0
> P3: cc00d718
> P4: StackHash_cad8
> P5: 0.0.0.0
> P6: 00000000
> P7: c0000008
> P8: PCH_E2_FROM_ntdll+0x0006A2DC
> P9:
> P10:
>
> Attached files:
> \?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WERB1A6.tmp.dmp
> \?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WERB427.tmp.WERInternalMetadata.xml
> \?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WERB486.tmp.xml
> \?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WERB494.tmp.csv
> \?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WERB4D3.tmp.txt
>
> These files may be available here:
> C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportArchive\AppCrash_HelloWorldTest3._40a823464c1b7f1a36d57ccec8a525baac94eb58_92da583c_48deb87c
>
> Analysis symbol:
> Rechecking for solution: 0
> Report Id: a085ff02-7bff-4a22-8d90-3f52094b2f8f
> Report Status: 268435456
> Hashed bucket: 334244e30a9d2a234f23a4b15a46766d
> Cab Guid: 0

Does this tell anything about why it crashed? I also have a list of .dlls that were loaded at the time, but I cannot see anything in particular that would cause it to crash.

UPDATE #2:

I tried rebooting in Safe Mode. That fixed the issue. So, then I tried restarting services one-by-one to find the one that was causing the debugger to crash. But, Windows would not allow me to start any additional services in Safe Mode. So, I decided to try it in the opposite direction. I rebooted in normal mode and started turning off services one-by-one. In the end, I had every service Windows would allow me to turn off set to off, but the issue was still occurring. This is looking more and more like a Windows Update broke something.

UPDATE #3: We activated our Microsoft Technical Support Contract. The Support Engineer they assigned had me send memory dumps and results from running Procmon during the APPCRASH event. After I sent the information, I have yet to hear back and still no word on what could be going wrong. The engineer has been ignoring my emails for the past two days (Friday last week and Monday this week). So, I cannot even get an update on progress. This is an extremely frustrating issue to troubleshoot, as it does not really generate easily found error messages. I will keep updating as I learn more. Thanks to all who have tried to help.

UPDATE #4:
Microsoft reviewed the dump files and the Procmon results. They discovered the error is in the CLR (which is odd, because VS 2013 can debug without issue...) It is specifically in the following dll method:
win32u!NtUserMsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx

Microsoft says the dump did not contain the details of that issue, and they would continue working on the issue. In the meantime, I uninstalled Trend Micro, restarted my computer, uninstalled VS 2017, restarted my computer, reinstalled VS 2017, restarted my computer, and the VS 2017 debugger still does not work. I also repaired every .NET Framework version in case any of them were corrupted, restarted again, just in case I hadn't rebooted enough, and still no luck. The only thing that has worked is booting the computer in safe mode.

Comment: I'd try the repair option in the Visual Studio Installer (click the More dropdown). If that doesn't work possibly an issue with your Windows installation. Maybe try system file checker, etc. Sorry not familiar with this problem but it seems to be an installation issue of Visual Studio or Windows as far as I can see from searches.

Comment: Was 'googling' this, and at:  https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/202833/debug-test-fails-after-reinstall-of-vs2017-v156-pr.html ; it isn't an "exact" replication of your issue as they are discussing unit testings, the very last comment in the thread is:  Added a solution by Viktor Veis [MSFT] · Jul 14 at 03:49 AM

Thank you for your feedback! We have fixed this issue and it's available in 15.7. Thank you for helping us build a better Visual Studio!  

Maybe make sure you are downloading the latest and greatest Visual Studio 2017 Version... just a shot in the dark.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a shot!

Comment: Visual Studio is updated to the latest and greatest version. I am updating the individual components now, as well (apparently, one component offered a newer version). I will check for Windows updates next.

Comment: Try saving project by using menu File : SaveAll.  Without saving the project is put in the users temporary space which may not have a crednentals to run.

Comment: Good thought, @jdweng! But, it did not have any problems saving the project. I am a local admin on the machine where Visual Studio is running. And this is only an issue for VS 2017. It works fine in VS 2013.

Comment: @Tone thank you for the advice. I have now repaired Visual Studio. I am checking my Windows installation, but so far, I have not found anything amiss.

Comment: Are you targeted for a version of Net that you have installed on PC.

Comment: @jdweng I'll check that out. I started removing components that I had installed and reinstalling them before I reinstalled Visual Studio completely. So, I will get back to you once the reinstall of the components completes.

Comment: @jdweng I can run the compiled program from the command line.

Comment: Did you take the compiled version from the Debug Folder or the Release Folder?  Check the timestamp of the executable in the Debug Folder and the Release Folder to see if both were updated with latest changes.

Comment: Debug. There is no release folder.

Comment: What happens when you right click on the visual studio 2017 icon and choose "run as administrator"?  I'd also go into my windows temp and user temp directories and clear those out.  Also, consider it may not be visual studio 2017 causing the problem, it may be another app installed and visual studio is merely the symptom.

Comment: I have the shortcut to VS set to always run as administrator. I can try it not running as administrator... And VS 2013 has no problems debugging on the same machine. It seems unlikely that the problem is another app that only affects one version of Visual Studio and not the other, but I suppose it is possible. I already tried disabling my anti-virus software to see if that was causing the conflict, as that is a common cause of issues but to no avail.

Comment: @Phill same issue when running "not" as an administrator. I get the same error message either way.

Comment: @InterstellarProbe bah, my thinking was perhaps it was some sort of permissions problem, browsing the hresult google results here, I get the impression that it could still be a permission thing or a missing DLL file that it cannot find.  Presumably it has worked at some point?  Can you think back to something new you've installed that aligns with when you discovered it broken?

Comment: I came back from a 3 week vacation and it was no longer working. The only update that I know of was a few Windows updates.

Comment: Nothing that a disk reformat could not fix.  But you're liable to put the same anti-malware product back, so start there first.

Comment: @HansPassant We disabled the anti-malware software. The issue persisted. I noticed that some of the services associated with the anti-malware software were slow to stop, so I thought maybe I had just attempted it too soon. So, we tried again, but waited ten minutes before debugging. It still did not work. Is it possible that there is some remnant of the service still in memory that may be causing the issue?

Comment: `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WERB1A6.tmp.dmp` it should tell what exactly happened, so in your case, wait for a reply from Microsoft.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know it has been two years, but I forgot about this after the issue was solved a couple of weeks later. Microsoft eventually found the issue was software my company was using to monitor employee activity, Veriato.

Once they disabled that software, Visual Studio worked without issue. Veriato eventually released a patch for it. But, it was software I was not even aware was on my machine because it has a similar code pattern to a virus, so it hides. Microsoft even had trouble finding it. Eventually, our IT department recognized the name of one of the files and put it together that was what was causing the issue.